# DataGridRowDetails - Toggling issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am having a `DataGrid` containing some Jobs.
What every job is doing is shown in the `RowDetails`.

Here I got multiple problems:

**Problem:** Why is the `Image`on the `ToggleButton` only shown on the `Selected` and the last Row ?

This is my `xaml`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=DetailsVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">                                   
        <ToggleButton.Style>
          <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="..\Resources\ic_expand_less_48px.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="..\Resources\ic_expand_more_48px.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="Content">
                   <Setter.Value>
                     <Image Source="..\Resources\ic_expand_more_48px.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                   </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
               </Trigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
         </ToggleButton.Style>
       </ToggleButton>
     </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when Style uses a UIElement for Content property (Image in this case),  it creates a single instance of that element. When Style is applied to multiple controls only one of them display Content because UIElement cannot have multiple parents.

That is why in most cases custom templates are used. ToggleButton has ContentTemplate property to customize the appearance of content part: (the same code for other two triggers)

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="..\Resources\ic_expand_more_48px.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

I know another method with non-shared resource:

```
<Image x:Key="ExpandMoreImg" x:Shared="False"
       Source="..\Resources\ic_expand_more_48px.png" Height="16" Width="16" />

<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ExpandMoreImg}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Shared is set to false and there will be an instance of Image for each usage

Comment: I addressed only Problem1, since Problem2 lacks MCVE and should be a seperate question in my opinion

Comment: yeah thought about splitting it too. Will do that later thanks for your help so far.